# Rails Routing - Reject any/all extensions?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, routes

I want to make a GET request to **/session/update** and return a JSON response. I have this working right now with the following route:

```
get 'session/update', to: 'user_sessions#keep_alive'
```

However, this route allows requests that have any type of extension tacked on to the end of it (**/session/update.txt**, **/session/update.abc123**, etc.). How can I write a route that rejects any request that includes an extension? I want to lock it down so that it ONLY responds to **/session/update**.

Comment: Is my answer worked for you?

Answer (score 0):

You can add a route constraint with an empty format:

```
get 'session/update', to: 'user_sessions#keep_alive', constraints: {format: nil}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with ***constraints*** like below

```
scope :format => true, :constraints => { :format => 'json' } do
  get 'session/update', to: 'user_sessions#keep_alive'
end
```